# Redirect admin and users to different pages login after fail Authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, owin, asp.net-identity-2

I'm writing an web application and I would like to do unauthorized request from AdminControler will redirect to Login method in AdminController, and for unauthorized users from UserController redirect to Login method in UserController. I wrote something like this, but i got error... My class attribute was added in filterConfig.

```
 public class AdminAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var ctx = filterContext.HttpContext.GetOwinContext();
        if (!ctx.Authentication.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            ctx.Authentication.SignOut();
            var controler = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
            var url = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.FilePath;
            if (controler.Equals("Admin"))
            {
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("~/Admin/Login"); //exception
            }
            else
            {
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("~/Account/Login"); //exception
            }

        }
        else
        {
            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
        }

    }
}
```

Exception: An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code
Inner exception: After sending the HTTP headers that the server can not attach headers.

I will be grateful for your help!

Comment: Does the exception have an inner exception?

Comment: i got this: After sending the HTTP headers that the server can not attach headers.

Comment: look at some of these answers and see if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435716/asp-net-response-redirect-not-working-in-application-error

Answer (score 0):

Use following code instead of using `Response.Redirect`. Redirect cause the headers to change and you cannot change the headers after they have been set.

```
filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Admin/Login");
```

Comment: i used your code, and exception was gone, but OnAuthorization method is still called and the program will loops. After this got Invalid redirecterror ;/

Comment: probably need to add this prior to issue the redirect `HttpContext.Current.ClearError();`