# ASP.NET Request Validator allowed scripts

Tags: c#, asp.net, request-validation

I have been working on `ASP.NET` Project
My `Request Validator` is default `true`
As a result dangerous script attacks are not allowed and ASP.NET throws me error 
Dangerous Requests

```
<script>alert('hello')</script>
```

which is very good. security

But why my below script is not blocked,ASP.NET request validator did not blocked below script

```
<%tag style=xss:expression(alert('hello'))>
```

This was not blocked and was fired

My Questions

```
1) <%tag style=xss:expression(alert('hello'))>
why this request was not blocked

2) <script>alert('hello')</script> 
This request was blocked and ASP.NET throws me to yellow error page
Is there any way to show error on the same page
```

Please Help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1) This article might help you understand validaterequest better :
https://infosecauditor.wordpress.com/2013/05/27/bypassing-asp-net-validaterequest-for-script-injection-attacks/

Some excerpts :

> ValidateRequest is present in ASP.NET versions 1, 2 and 3. ASP.NET
>   version 4 does not use the ValidateRequest filter.
>
> ValidateRequest validates user input and returns false when the
>   following conditions are met:
>
> ```
> <a-z     –    A ‘<’ character followed by an alpha character.
> <!, </, <?     –    A ‘<’ character followed by a special character.
> &,#    –    A special character.
> ```

You can write your own custom validator which extends RequestValidator & takes care of these things.
[Eg:](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/ASP.NET_Request_Validation)

2) 
`Is there any way to show error on the same page`

Yes. but then you will have to validate the input by yourself & say bye to asp.net benefits https://gargmanoj.wordpress.com/tag/httprequestvalidationexception/

No. because an Application Error has happened & asp.net has stopped processing it. But you can definitely show a custom error page.

See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028206/how-to-catch-httprequestvalidationexception-in-production) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435716/asp-net-response-redirect-not-working-in-application-error):

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var context = HttpContext.Current;
    var exception = context.Server.GetLastError();
    if (exception is HttpRequestValidationException)
    {
HttpContext.Current.Server.ClearError();
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/ErrorPage.aspx");

        return;
    }
}
```

There is also an option for [AntiXss](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.antixss.antixssencoder(v=vs.110).aspx) encoder class for encoding the output values.

```
<httpRuntime encoderType="System.Web.Security.AntiXss.AntiXssEncoder" />
```